# Tabbed content with toggle buttons and class to disable toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get this script to have toggleable tabs. As of rite now, all the content is hidden to begin with, then when I hit a tab button, that tab content appears.

I would like it if I click the same tab again, it would hide the content.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('div.tabs a').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})
```

And me trying to get it to work, but it is removing the 'current' class every button click, so it will always stay hidden.

```
$('div.tabs a').click(function(){
    if ( $("div.tabs a").hasClass("current") ) {
        $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current')};
    else (
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    )
})
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL90n9o8/

// Edit

Added to the end of the 'if' statement to see if I could make it so when it has the '.close' class, it will make it so the tabs cannot close, but this does not work.

What I am trying to do is make it look for two classes before you can click the tab to close it. If it does not have those two classes, it will not close the tab. Hopefully i explained myself good enough.

```
$('div.tabs a').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('current') && $(this).hasClass('close')){ // Added new code to the end
    //if($(this).is('.current, .close')){ // Or maybe something like this? But this does not work.
        $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        $('.content').removeClass('current');        
    }else{    
     var tabid = $(this).attr('data-content');
     //var tabid = $(this).data('content'); //You can use this line instead of above line as well
     $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
     $('.content').removeClass('current');
     $(this).addClass('current');
     $("#" + tabid).addClass('current');
 }    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this as well. As mentioned before you have to check for the class `current` if it exists for the clicked tab then remove it else add class `current` to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <a class="tab-link" data-content="tab-1">tab1</a>
    <a class="tab-link" data-content="tab-2">tab2</a>
    <a class="tab-link" data-content="tab-3">tab3</a>
</div>


<div id="tab-1" class="content">1</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="content">2</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="content">3</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('div.tabs a').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('current')){
        $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        $('.content').removeClass('current');        
    }else{    
        var tabid = $(this).attr('data-content');
        //var tabid = $(this).data('content'); //You can use this line instead of above line as well
        $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        $('.content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tabid).addClass('current');
    }    
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bL90n9o8/2/)**

**UPDATED**

For the next part of the question, you probably need to do the following:

```
$('div.tabs a').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('current')){
        if($(this).hasClass('close')){
            $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        }else{
            $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
            $('.content').not('.close').removeClass('current');        
        }    
    }else{    
        var tabid = $(this).attr('data-content');
        //var tabid = $(this).data('content');
        $('div.tabs a').removeClass('current');
        $('.content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tabid).addClass('current');
    }    
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bL90n9o8/3/)**

Comment: This works perfect. I'm also wondering if there is a way to make it so if the a tab has a class, it cant be closed. I have updated my first post to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the div related to the clicked link already has the `current` class and if so, hide it instead of showing it:

```
$('div.tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tabid = $(this).attr('href');
    var hasClass = $(tabid).hasClass('current');

    $('div.tabs a, .content').removeClass('current');
    !hasClass && $(this).add(tabid).addClass('current');
})
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bL90n9o8/1/)

Also note that I removed your `tdata` attribute as it is invalid, and instead used the `href` to link the related div.